# How can I change Windows 8.1 key to Windows 10 key?

Tags: windows, windows-key

I bouth laptop with pre-installed windows 8.1 a half year ago. 
I copied license key and erased the system.

I installed windows 10 and I want to activate it with my key, but it does not accept it.

Is there any way to convert the key?

Because I do not want to install windows 8.1 with my key and then upgrade to windows 10.

Comment: You should know by now that this question is off topic for this site.

Comment: Might I suggest you post this on http://superuser.com/?  As @crashmstr rightfully points out, Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this unfortunately.

You will have to re-install Windows 8.1, then upgrade to Windows 10, then use the Reset Process in Windows 10 for a clean install.

To reset your Windows 10 PC, open the Settings app, select Update & security, select Recovery, and click the “Get started” button under Reset this PC. Select “Remove everything.” This will wipe all your files, so be sure you have backups.